# Por que não quer incrementar?

Tags: c

Eu quero que incremente a variável cont caso o vetor de caractere não seja nulo, entende? Mas não acontece nada. Por quê?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void main(){

int i;
char testeNome[190];
int cont;
printf("Digite seu primeiro nome: ");
scanf("%s",testeNome);


while(testeNome != "\0"){

    cont++; 
    }

printf("%d",cont);
}
```

Comment: Ps.: Não posso usar strlen por isso quero descobrir o valor do tamanho do vetor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amiga, segue o código funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){

int i = 0;
char testeNome[190];
int cont = 0;
printf("Digite seu primeiro nome: ");
scanf("%s",testeNome);

while(testeNome[i] != '\0'){
    cont++;
    i++;
}

printf("%d",cont);
}
```

você esqueceu de usar a variável i para tratar os caracteres da string, utilizando-o em testeNome e incrementando o i dentro do loop. Além disso, como \0 se trata de um caractere, precisamos indica-lo por aspas simples.

Aah, e é sempre bom iniciar as variáveis (cont e i) com 0 para evitar que tenham algum valor de uma execução anterior.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Amiga* sou mulher = P

Comment: Opa! força do hábito, peço desculpas rsrs

Comment: rs =]. Relaxa. obrigada por ajudar. =]